# Silverlight - (Xaml) File corrupted?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

my file xaml n its cs file was open in Visual studio 2010 when power got off. Now when power got back and i opened my project.. i cant open that xaml n cs file. I can open all my other xaml n cs file of that project. But cant open those two files only.

on xaml page i get n error

```
An unhandled exception has occured 

Details:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80041FEB

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode,   IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
at MS.Internal.Providers.DocDataFactory.CreateAndRegisterDocData(IServiceProvider services, String fileName)
at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.GetDocData(String fileName)
at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.Initialize(IServiceProvider provider, IVsHierarchy hierarchy, UInt32 itemid, Object docDataObj)
at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext..ctor(IServiceProvider provider, IVsWindowFrame frame, Object docDataObj)
at MS.Internal.Providers.VSDesignerContext.GetContext(IServiceProvider services, IVsWindowFrame frame, Boolean createIfNotExist)
at MS.Internal.Designer.TabbedEditorPane.MS.Internal.Designer.ITabbedEditorService.get_DesignerContext()
at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.InitializeDesigner()
```

what the hell is this? is it corrupted or is something else?

and also i cant open cs file .. when i try to open it in visual studio it opens in Notepad.. and its blank.. nothing is in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does look like the power-loss corrupted the files.

The only two solutions I know:

1. Get the latest version from source control and redo the work of today
2. Start from scratch again (or any old copy)